# Storing Decl nodes in Clang AST

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-clang, clang-static-analyzer

I'm trying to store all FunctionDecl nodes in a vector so that I can visit them in the future. The use case would for stepping into functions (e.g. function a calls function b, I want to be able to call VisitDecl on the function b node)

Storing of all these nodes are done in the HandleTopLevelDecl within ASTConsumer:

```
std::vector<Decl> vec;

virtual bool HandleTopLevelDecl (DeclGroupRef DG) {
  for (DeclGroupRef::iterator i = DG.begin(), e = DG.end(); i != e; ++i) {
    Decl *D = *i;
    vec.push_back(*D);
  }
}
```

However, during compilation there is an error '~Decl' is a protected member of 'clang::Decl'

Anyone can shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are putting a copy of `Decl` instance into your array. Creation and deletion of these objects is responsibility of other class, hence you can only have a reference to an instance.

Here is proper solution for your problem:

```
std::vector<Decl *> vec;

virtual bool HandleTopLevelDecl (DeclGroupRef DG) {
  for (DeclGroupRef::iterator i = DG.begin(), e = DG.end(); i != e; ++i) {
    Decl *D = *i;
    vec.push_back(D);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem of adding it to a vector. Now all that's left to do is check if I can visit the node stored within the vectors. Cheers.